# Semantic way to add a "caption" inside a table

Tags: html, html-table, semantic-markup

I have a table that has a caption. To group related information together, I used `colspan` on the `<th>` rows (`Total divisions` and `Elevation`) so that they serve as "captions" for the cells below them. However, I am not sure if this is the appropriate way of doing it semantically. Particularly, how will I make sure that `Total divisions` and `Elevation` would only refer to the rows below them?

```html
<table>
  <caption>Summary</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>Santo Cristo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Area</th>
    <td>67.99 km<sup>2</sup></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" colspan="2">Total divisions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Cities</th>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Villages</th>
    <td>45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" colspan="2">Elevation (masl)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Highest point</th>
    <td>12 meters</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Lowest point</th>
    <td>0 meters</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your rows into `<tbody>` elements and scope each summary `<th>` to its parent `<tbody>` with `scope="rowgroup"` in lieu of `scope="row"`, like so:

```html
<table>
  <caption>Summary</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <td>Santo Cristo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Area</th>
      <td>67.99 km<sup>2</sup></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="rowgroup" colspan="2">Total divisions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Cities</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Villages</th>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="rowgroup" colspan="2">Elevation (masl)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Highest point</th>
      <td>12 meters</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Lowest point</th>
      <td>0 meters</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

(The first group can be either a `<thead>` or another `<tbody>` depending on your preference, but what's important are the two groups you're trying to scope the `<th>` elements to.)

Comment: Thank you. I never thought `tbody` could be used multiple times.